# javascript Hangman game issue with api

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a Hangman game written in JavaScript using the CreateJS library. The game uses the fetch API to get a random word from an external API (https://random-word-api.vercel.app/), and then generates a hidden word from the random word. The game also uses jQuery to handle button clicks and keyboard events. However, the hidden word as a series of question marks is not displayed initially, until I click on a button, and I want the ?????? word to be visible initially. Also the game is not completely reset after 'you win' or 'you lose' title and old word is still displayed. Can you help me clear that old word and generate new? I tried to optimize createGuessWord() and doGameOver() functions but I had no luck. Here is my code:

```js
window.onload=function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

var alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
var theWord = "";
var guessWord = [];
var newGuessWord = "";
var numWrong = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var guessedLetters = [];
var hangmanShape = new createjs.Shape();
var theWordText = new createjs.Text("", "bold 35px Arial", "#000000");
var theOutComeText = new createjs.Text("", "bold 50px Arial", "#FF0000");
theOutComeText.x = 90;
theOutComeText.y = 200;
theWordText.x = 50;
theWordText.y = 27;
stage.addChild(theWordText, theOutComeText);
stage.addChild(hangmanShape);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
function handleTick(event) {
  stage.update()
}


function startGame() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.clear();
    createGuessWord();
    drawCanvas();
    theOutComeText.text = "";
    enableButtons();
    addKeyListener();
    
}

async function createGuessWord() {
    guessWord = new Array(theWord.length).fill("?");
    const response = await fetch('https://random-word-api.vercel.app/api?words=1&type=uppercase');
    const data = await response.json();
    theWord = data[0].toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < theWord.length; i++) {
        guessWord[i] = "?";
    }
    newGuessWord = guessWord.join("");
}

 

function drawGallows() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(120, 305);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(280, 305);
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(260, 305);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(260, 70);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(180, 70);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(180, 96);


}

function drawHead() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.arc(180, 120, 23, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    hangmanShape.graphics.closePath();

}

function drawBody() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(180, 143);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(180, 248);

}

function drawArm1() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(180, 175);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(142, 167);

}

function drawArm2() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(180, 175);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(218, 167);

}

function drawLeg1() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(180, 245);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(145, 270);

}

function drawLeg2() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.moveTo(180, 245);
    hangmanShape.graphics.lineTo(215, 270);

}

function drawHangman(drawNum) {
    hangmanShape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke("rgba(0,0,0,1)");
    switch (drawNum) {
        case 0:
            drawGallows();
            break;
        case 1:
            drawHead();
            break;
        case 2:
            drawBody();
            break;
        case 3:
            drawArm1();
            break;
        case 4:
            drawArm2();
            break;
        case 5:
            drawLeg1();
            break;
        case 6:
            drawLeg2();
            break;
    }
}

function drawCanvas() {
   hangmanShape.graphics.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i <= numWrong; i++) {
        drawHangman(i);
    }

    if (gameOver) {
        disableButtons();
        removeKeyListener();
        theOutComeText.text = "You lose!";
        theOutComeText.color = "#FF0000";
        theWordText.text = theWord;
        setTimeout(function(){ doGameOver() }, 3000);
    } else {
        theWordText.text = newGuessWord;
    }

}
for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArray.length; i++) {
    $('<button/>', {
        text: alphabetArray[i],
        id: 'btn_' + alphabetArray[i],
        width: "30px",
        click: function (event) {
            checkGuess(event, false);
        }
    }).appendTo("#buttondiv");
}

function disableButtons() {
    $("#buttondiv button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
disableButtons();

function enableButtons() {
    $("#buttondiv button").removeAttr("disabled");
}

function addKeyListener() {
    $(document).on("keyup", function (event) {
        checkGuess(event, true);

    });
}

function removeKeyListener() {
    $(document).off("keyup");
}
function checkGuess(event,isKeyPress){
        var currentButton;
        var theLetter;
        var RegEx = /[a-zA-Z]/;
        var correctGuess = false;

    if(isKeyPress){
        currentButton = "btn_"+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        theLetter = $("#"+currentButton).text().toLowerCase();
        $("#"+currentButton).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        if(!RegEx.test(theLetter)){
            return;
        }
    }else{
       currentButton = $(event.target);
       $(currentButton).attr("disabled", "disabled");
       theLetter = $(currentButton).text().toLowerCase();
    }
    
    if(guessedLetters.indexOf(theLetter) >=0){
        return;
    }else{
        guessedLetters.push(theLetter);
    }
        
        for(var i =0;i<theWord.length;i++){
            if(theWord.charAt(i) == theLetter){
                guessWord[i] = theLetter;
                correctGuess = true;
            }
        }
            newGuessWord = guessWord.join("");
            
        if(!correctGuess){
            numWrong++
        }
        if(newGuessWord == theWord){
          disableButtons();
          removeKeyListener();
          theOutComeText.text = "You win!";
          theOutComeText.color = "#00FF00";
          theWordText.text = theWord;
          setTimeout(function(){ doGameOver() },3000);
        }
        if(numWrong == 6){
            gameOver = true;
        }
        drawCanvas();
    }
    function doGameOver(){
    numWrong = 0;
    gameOver = false;
    guessedLetters = new Array();
    startGame();
    }
    
 
startGame();
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:powderblue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="400" height="320"></canvas>

    <div id="buttondiv">

    </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: In theory you should limit your question to one specific problem, and narrow the code to a minimal part where the problem happens, as it is currently, you are asking us to debug your code. Better to teach one to fish rather than give you a fish as the proverb goes. What do you get when you log your variables in `createGuessWord`? Did you check that this function is called at all before you press the buttons? Are all the variables properly filled for example when you fill `guessWord `, like `theWord`?

Comment: off topic: Why request `&type=uppercase` then immediately convert it to lowercase?

Comment: In addition to comment above, the bit to debug is `drawCanvas()` as that draws the "newGuessWord` - so change you code to ` function drawCanvas() { console.log(newGuessWord);` and run with the console open - then step backwards to see where `newGuessWord` *should* have been defined.

Comment: It seems your problem is quite simple, check in your code where the word is displayed, eg the lines where you have`theWordText.text = `. You can add a console.log in all these lines to verify when your word display is updated. Shouldn't you be doing it when a game start? When you get your code working, I suggest you submit it to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to have advice on how to organize your code too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be clear from stepping through the code:

Your issue is that `createGuessWord()` is **async** and you're not waiting for the result - so `drawCanvas()` executes *before* `createGuessWord()` has set `newGuessWord` (which is why it's blank on first run).

When you click a letter button, the `fetch()` has completed and `newGuessWord` is ready to be guessed against.

You can fix this by making `startGame()` also async:

```
  async function startGame() {
    hangmanShape.graphics.clear();
    await createGuessWord();
    drawCanvas();
```

Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/4bzdkxt7/